# How to use subdomain in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

is it possible to somehow work with subdomain in Nuxt 3?

So that instead of such a link:
https://example.com/projects/19302847

I could use one like this:
https://19302847.example.com

Answer (score 2):

To handle subdomain routing in nuxt, create two folders in the pages directory

pages 
|-root-domain
|-- // files and folders  
|- sub-domain
|-- //files and folders

then using the rouet option config in the `app/router.options.ts`, add the following configuration:

```
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig> {
    routes: (_routes) => {
        let routesDirectory: any = null;
        const { ssrContext } = useNuxtApp();

        // check for subdomain in the url on the server
        if (process.server && ssrContext && ssrContext.event.node.req) {
            const req = ssrContext.event.node.req
            const subdomain = req.headers.host?.split('.')[0]
            if (subdomain !== 'www' && subdomain !== 'localhost' && subdomain !== 'localhost:3000') {
                routesDirectory = 'sub-domain'
            } else {
                routesDirectory = 'root-domain'
            }

        }

        // check for subdomain in the url on the client
        if (process.client && window.location.hostname) {
            const subdomain = window.location.hostname.split('.')[0]
            if (subdomain !== 'www' && subdomain !== 'localhost'  && subdomain !== 'localhost:3000') {
                routesDirectory = 'sub-domain'
            } else {
                routesDirectory = 'root-domain'
            }
        }

        // function to clear a directory not in use
        function isUnderDirectory (route: any, directory: any) {
            const path = route.path
            return path === '/' + directory || path.startsWith('/' + directory + '/')
        }

        let newRoutes = _routes

        if (routesDirectory) {
            // filter routes
            newRoutes = _routes.filter((route: any) => {
                const toRemove = routesDirectory === 'sub-domain' ? 'root-domain' : 'sub-domain'
                return !isUnderDirectory(route, toRemove)
            }).map((route: any) => {
                if (isUnderDirectory(route, 'sub-domain')) {
                    return {
                        ...route,
                        path: route.path.replace('/sub-domain', '/'),
                        name: route.name || 'index'
                    }
                } else if (isUnderDirectory(route, 'root-domain')) {
                    return {
                        ...route,
                        path: route.path.substr(routesDirectory.length + 1) || '/',
                        name: route.name || 'index'
                    }
                }
            })

        return newRoutes
        }

    }
}
```